# Concatenate json file with a variable

Tags: json, lua, coronasdk

I would like to concatenate a variable with a table in a file called items.json.  My attributes inside of the files are called "pos1_name", "pos2_name", etc... So I would like to use the number in the attribute name, as a variable. I've try : `item.pos..i.._name` but it doesn't work.

```
 items = VarLoad.loadTable("items.json")

  for i=1,7  do
            --var ="1"
            --print(table.concat(items,"",2))
                if items.pos1=="1" then
                        item[i] = display.newImageRect("items/"..items.pos1_name..".png", 80 , 80)
                        item[i].x = holder[i].x+10
                        item[i].anchorX=0
                        item[i].y=holder[i].y
                        itemGroup:insert (item[i])
                        item[i].destination="item1"
                        item[i]:addEventListener( "touch", onSwitchPress )

                        item_bigsize[i] = display.newImageRect("items/"..items.pos1_name..".png", 240 , 240)
                        item_bigsize[i].x = 950
                        item_bigsize[i].anchorX=0
                        item_bigsize[i].y=display.contentCenterY-130
                        group:insert (item_bigsize[i])
                        item_bigsize[i].isVisible=true       


                end
        i=i+1
    end
```

Comment: What error do you get and what does it print?

Try to add `print("items/"..items.pos1_name..".png")` and report back.

Comment: "items/"..items.pos1_name..".png" works very well ! What i'm trying to do is to concatenate "items.pos..i.._name". It says : Attempt to concatenate with a field ? (a nil value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My attributes inside of the files are called "pos1_name", "pos2_name", etc... So I would like to use the number in the attribute name, as a variable. I've try : item.pos..i.._name but it doesn't work.

You need to use full table notation: `items.pos1_name` is a shortcut for `items['pos1_name']`, so if you need to generate the key dynamically, you can use something like this:

```
print(items['pos'..i..'name'])
```